# Prevent button width from changing Basic CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

Basic css question here.

Every time I press "Check all", the button populates with the names from a list (which is fine).

The issue is: The button width itself expands and gets bigger. I want to keep it fixed. Furthermore, how can I set a limit to the number of list items it can show? So for example, if there are a lot of items, after "test 5", a "..." should appear.

By the way: this is all in my custom.css, .btn-default is actually from bootstrap, but I wanted to change some things in my multi select-class. I changed caret margin because the caret was right beside the text, I wanted it to be to the VERY right, maybe that's what's messing everything up??

custom.css  :

```
    .sv-manage-multiselect-dropdown {

        .btn-default {
            background-image: none;
            border: 1px solid #ADA9A9;
            padding: 6px 8px 1px 8px ;
            }

        .btn .caret {
            margin-left: 160px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
    }
```

Html:

```
<td class="col-xs-2">
    <am-multiselect class="sv-manage-multiselect-dropdown"    
                    ng-model="Mylist.names"
                    options="Names.name for link in Mylist"
                    multiple="true"    
                    ms-selected="{{Mylist.names}}"                        
     </am-multiselect>        

</td>
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show the relevant HTML, and CSS you're using? Ideally with a live demo (such as a snippet here in your question, or in an external site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) *in addition to* the ("[MCVE]") code here in your question.

Comment: Hard to answer without html, but I think you just need to put a min-width to checkmark element.

Comment: @sylvain1264 
 

I added the html part where the multi-select button is. Mylist and names ( the items in this case) are comming from the backend api, as u see ng-model= "Mylist.names". Hard to setup a Jsfiddle because there are alot of files in this angular app. sorry I'm new to this stuff. btw:  min-width didn't work

Comment: Well, you added html of am-multiselect directive call but it does not help at all. Can you show us the html "am-multiselect" directive is generating ? I mean using element inspection of chrome browser for example. (When all is checked and unchecked).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using max-width in your css?

```
max-width: 40px;
```

For example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes i did. I added max-width to the btn-default. It still changes width when i press checkAll

Comment: Can you try to put this into a JSFiddle?

Comment: Not sure how I can. I'm using an external multiselect library ( https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect) and the list items are comming from an api. This is an angular app btw. There's alot of code in the project

Answer (score 0):

I looked in angular-multiselect/src/multiselect.tmpl.html, adding this css should work, 10px is just for the example, put width and height of the checkmark, like this `<i>` will fill same place even if it's void:

```
.sv-manage-multiselect-dropdown {
    ul.dropdown-menu > li > i{
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 10px;
        min-height: 10px;
    }
}
```